# RestKit Failed With Error clang failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios5, xcode4.2, clang, restkit

I have RestKit 0.9.3 Version and XCode 4.2
Followed the instructions on RestKit for installing on XCode 4.x and i the error mentioned below.

I googled a lot, check many stack answers but none server my problem. I checked the linker flags, they are configured as per the tutorial.

> Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

Error shown in the image:

[image]

Comment: guys who are reading this please give up on rest-kit and go with AFNetworking. Its amazing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you're building for the iPhone, just make sure you don't have the RestKit.framework added to your target; in the 'Link Binary With Libraries'. HTH

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue. I eventually started a fresh Xcode project, since my project was small, and it worked fine. I *suspect* this is because I had just converted to Xcode 4.2, and enabled ARC via the tool, I think some things were missed. When I made a fresh Xcode project with 4.2 and put my sources, then ResKit in, it worked just fine.

If your project is small this is a fairly low cost solution. If big, well, hopefully it works!

Yeah, I hate not knowing why, but I also hate wasting time.

Comment: I believe adding Restkit framework in link with library section has something to do with this and reinstalling is not helping.